# Program in c to print flloyd's triangle . Program stops working

Tags: c, arrays, string, loops, io

i wrote the following code in c to print floyd's triangle.

```
int main()
{
    printf("Enter the number of rows you want to have");
    int t;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    int i;
    char a[1000] ="";
    for(i=1;i<=t;i++)
    {
        if (i%2!=0)
        {
            strcat("1",a);
            printf("%c\n",a);}
        else
            strcat("0",a);
        printf("%c\n",a);


    }
    return 0;
}
```

The program seems fine to me but it stops working as soon as i execute it. Please help
I want to have the output as follows-
1
01
101
0101
10101
and so on

Comment: Also, you might want to add braces around the `else` statement; at moment, the second `printf("%c\n",a)` will get called regardless of the if-else block. Or you could just remove the first `printf("%c\n",a)` statement.

Comment: thanks a lot for helping. The program doesn't stop working now but i am still not getting the desired output. For example if i enter the number of rows as 4. i get 4 blank rows

Comment: i want the pattern to be like - 1  01 101 0101 10101 and so on .And each number in a new line

Comment: Please, add to the question your expected output. I don't know what do you mean with [Flloyd's triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%27s_triangle).

Comment: i have added the expected output in the code

Comment: i didn't get you

Comment: Are you explicitly asked to do that using a "growing" c string? Because a) It's not really necessary and b) you should append the last char to other side.

Comment: how to append the last char to the other side? And yeah i need to do this using a growing string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compile with warnings enabled and you will quickly see that you need to print `a` with `%s` (string format), rather than `%c` (character format). When I compiled your code, I got:

```
prog.c: In function 'main':
prog.c:16:22: warning: format '%c' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'char *' [-Wformat=]
             printf("%c\n",a);
                     ~^    ~
                     %s
prog.c:20:22: warning: format '%c' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'char *' [-Wformat=]
             printf("%c\n",a);
                     ~^    ~
                     %s
```

Moreover, your `else` statement lacks curly braces, which results in only the `strcat()` to be assumed as its body.

To get the desired output, you should abandon `strcat()` and index the position you want to assign the bit, like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Enter the number of rows you want to have\n");
    int t;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    int i;
    char a[1000] ="";
    for(i=1;i<=t;i++)
    {
        if (i%2!=0)
        {
            a[999 - i] = '1';
            printf("%s\n", &a[999 - i]);
        }
        else {
            a[999 - i] = '0';
            printf("%s\n", &a[999 - i]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Enter the number of rows you want to have
4
1
01
101
0101
```

Notice that `999` is the size of your array, minus 1.

---

PS: In your posted code: when concatenating the string, you messed up the order of the arguments.

Comment: This is not the output i am expecting from the program. I have mentioned the expected output in my question

Comment: @jamesgem The backwards `strcat` and the wrong format in `printf` are the reasons that your program crashed. You should be able to figure the rest out by yourself.

Comment: but i need to use the strcat in that way only else i'll get the output you are getting

Comment: can you please explain what a[999-i] is doing?

Comment: @gsamaras You should remove the first part of your answer (with the incorrect output) for brevity.

Comment: please explain to me what a[999-i] does ?

Comment: @jamesgem `i` is your counter. So when `i` is 0, then this `a[999 - i] = '1';` will assign 1 to `a[999]`, and so on.

Comment: @jamesgem This approach adds the alternating digits to the end of the string, but `printf()` prints from the start of the string, effectively reversing the output.

Answer (score 2):

You can construct the string (the bigger one) first and then print only a part of it in each row:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Enter the number of rows you want to have");
    int t;
    scanf("%d",&t); // You should check the return value...
    puts("");

    char pattern[t + 1]; // It's a VLA, so you need a C99 compliant compiler or
                         // use your big array...

    // Initialize the string (it's the last row) starting from the last 
    // char (the null terminator) and stepping back to first. Every row should
    // end with a '1', so in the loop, start with it.
    int i = t;
    pattern[i] = '\0';
    while ( i > 0 )
    {
        pattern[--i] = '1';
        if ( i == 0 )
            break;
        pattern[--i] = '0';
    }

    // Print only the part needed in each row
    char* tmp = &pattern[t - 1];
    for ( int i = 0; i < t; ++i, --tmp )
    {
        printf("%s\n", tmp);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should give you the output you're looking for:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Enter the number of rows you want to have: ");
    int t;
    scanf("%d", &t);

    for (int i = 1; i <= t; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
        {
            char a[1000] = "";

            if ((i+j) % 2 == 0)
                strcat(a, "1");
            else
                strcat(a, "0");

            printf("%s", a);
        }

        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Since every other line begins with a 0, you could simply recreate the string `a` per line.

Comment: why are we running two loops ?

Comment: The outer loop determines how long the string on the current line should be,  while the inner loop fills the string with alternating `1`s and `0`s. By checking for `(i+j) % 2`, you can determine if the current line should begin with a `1` or `0`. Otherwise, if you always check for `i % 2`, you will always begin with the same digit on each line.